# ConfidentialClientApplication Caching - GetAccountAsync

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

the
Lately I joined a project that is using Azure AD Open ID connect authentication code to authenticate with the ASP.Net Core web application.
When I am trying to run it locally I am facing issues with retrieving info with the GetAccountAsync method (Return null). From what I read, I think the code is missing a caching helper to cache the user/application tokens.

```
    public async Task<string> GetUserAccessTokenAsync(string userId)
    {
        var account = await _app.GetAccountAsync(userId);
    
        try
        {
            var result = await _app.AcquireTokenSilent(_scopes, account).ExecuteAsync();
            return result.AccessToken;
        }

        // Unable to retrieve the access token silently.
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(new Error
            {
                Code = GraphErrorCode.AuthenticationFailure.ToString(),
                Message = "Caller needs to authenticate. Unable to retrieve the access token silently."
            });
        }
    }
```

If anyone has any idea what I could do to fix this issue Ill be happy to know :)

Thank you!

Comment: If you are using MSAL.NET it has in-memory token cache is provided by default. Here is the documentation for [token cache and serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-token-cache-serialization).  Can you try with API `var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();` as mentioned in this this [documentation](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-a-cached-token#recommended-call-pattern-in-public-client-applications-with-msalnet-3x)?

Comment: Thank you for your input. The documentation shows the API flow using a PublicClientApplication rather than a ConfidentialClientApplication. (Which doesnt support AcquireTokenInteractive)

Comment: There is no user context for ConfidentialClientApplication, The MSAL API `AcquireTokenForClient` takes care of token cache it. Here is the [documentation](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-credential-flows#acquiretokenforclient-uses-the-application-token-cache) for details.

Comment: Looks good, thank you! One thing though is now that I forward the scopes: 
`_scopes = new string[] { "User.Read", "Directory.Read.All" }` to `AcquireTokenForClient`, it says:  `The scope Directory.Read.All User.Read is not valid.`

Comment: @IddoBotzer Does this issue resolved? can you please help how it is solved. I am also facing same issue